# Textarea placeholder with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I'm trying to change the placeholder of a textarea with the press of a checkbox button. I just can't get it to change.

To be clear, I'm trying to set a placeholder NOT a value.

My textarea:

```html
<textarea name="problem" id="problem" rows="3" class="form-control" cols="45" placeholder="Describe your ticket reason in as few words as possible."></textarea>
```

My JavaScript:

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="changeplh()" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="1" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
  <script>
    function changeplh() {
      debugger;
      var sel = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch");
      var textbx = document.getElementById("problem");
      var indexe = sel.selectedIndex;

      if (indexe == 0) {
        $("#problem").val('');
        $("#problem").prop("placeholder", "age");

      }
      if (indexe == 1) {
        $("#problem").val('');
        $("#problem").prop("placeholder", "name");
      }
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

What I specifically need - a checkbox button that changes a placeholder of a textarea to 2 different options.
EX: Click it once, it says "age", click it again it says "name", click it again it says "age" etc.

Comment: you have `indexe = sel.selectedIndex`, but the element with id of `myonoffswitch` is not a `<select>` element, also your textarea does not have an id of `problem`

Comment: @PatrickEvans stupid me, I posted the wrong textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a little bit messy (for example, you have no `#problem` in your code) so I just created a simple demo of changing the `placeholder`.

```js
$('#problem').change(function() {
  $('textarea').attr('placeholder', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'name' : 'age');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" style="height:150px" name="techProblem" placeholder="Describe the issue in as few words as possible."></textarea>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="problem" /> Change placeholder</label>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this effect every single input on the page? WHen anyo f them are changed, it would change my textarea no? I need a specific checkbox to change a specific textarea. Also, edited my post a bit for a bit more requirements.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's just a demo. If you want to do this only for specific `textarea` and specific `checkbox` you have to use more specific selector. like `$('#checkbox_id').change` etc. I just was updated my answer.

Comment: I still can't get it to do anything.

Comment: Got it! But how can I make it so it switches between 2 different placeholders every time the button is pressed?

Comment: which button? Are you mean `button` instead of `checkbox`?

Comment: I don't understand. In my snippet, at first the placeholder is `Describe the issue in as few words as possible.` After the first click the placeholder is `name`. After the second click the placeholder is `age`. What behavior you expect?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your edit. That is EXACTLY what I wanted, thank you so much.